# Cakephp Error: The Categories association is not defined on Carts

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

You can see I have used $this->loadModel('Categories');  in my Cart controller function.

```
  public function home($cat_id=null, $subcat_id=null)
    {
         // Set leftmenu 
        $this->loadModel('Categories'); 
        $query = $this->Categories->find('all', [
            'contain' => ['SubCategories']
        ]);
        $this->set('categories', $query);
        
        // Set conditions
        $conditions = array();
        if (!empty($cat_id)) {
            $conditions['Products.category_id'] = $cat_id;
        }
        if (!empty($subcat_id)) {
            $conditions['Products.sub_category_id'] = $subcat_id;
        }
                
        $this->paginate = [
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'contain' => ['Categories', 'SubCategories', 'Discounts' => function ($q) {
                return $q
                    ->where(['Discounts.start_at <' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'Discounts.end_at >' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')])
                    ->limit(1);
            }]
        ];
        $this->set('products', $this->paginate($this->Products));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['products']);
    }
```

When I add the items in the cart and click the cart button to view the items then I get this error.

Comment: It is clear, the carts and categories controller are not associated. You need to make a join first either via models or join SQL statements or using CakePHP recommended like naming `categories.cart_id = carts.id`

Comment: which cakephp version are you exactly using? 1.x and 3.x uses diffrent approaches while loading models..

Comment: it's 4.1.0 How to know that its which .x . Is it 4x ?

Comment: ok, 4.x version that is sufficient to know. Now please post your model of categories and carts.